# how to use gettimeofday() to get the current date

Tags: linux, assembly

I am trying to get the current date using assembly (x86) on Linux. I wrote the following program:

```
[BITS   32]

%assign SYS_GETTIMEOFDAY        78

[SECTION        .text]
[GLOBAL _start]
_start:
        ;get the system date
        mov     dword eax, SYS_GETTIMEOFDAY
        int     byte 0x80
        test    eax, eax
        js      error
done:
        convert
error:
        whatever
```

I would expect to get the tv struct address on ebx so i can access the secs in 0(%ebx) and microsecs in 4(%ebx), but after debugging the code i get $ebx=0x0. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it backwards.  Instead of expecting the kernel to give you a `struct timeval *` through ebx, you should give one to the kernel, and it will modify it.